# SELECT DISTINCT from a specific column for dropdownlist

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I am looking to write a query to only give back distinct results for a drop down list. Note: I have alot of tables FULL OUTER JOINED together so when I run a SELECT DISTINCT query it still gives me all of the rows that are distinct but I want the column data to be distinct.

Example:

```
ColA    ColB
A        a
A        a
A        c
B        b     
B        a
C        b
```

DropDown List1 Result(For ColA):

```
 DropDownList
     A
     B
     C
```

DropDown List2 Result(For ColB):

```
 DropDownList
     a
     b
     c
```

Comment: Use two separate queries: `SELECT DISTINCT ColA FROM MyTable` and `SELECT DISTINCT ColB FROM MyTable`.

Comment: If you are using the result of the query for something other than populating the dropdownlist, then you have to iterate over the result or use LINQ to achieve your result.

Comment: @Linger So there is no way to combine the queries to Get Same Result? For example, SELECT DISTINCT ColA,ColB. Then DropDownList1 Values = ColA and DropDownList2 Values = ColB

Comment: **@user3339242**, no not really.  Why would you want to combine them anyway?

Comment: @user2989408 Yes I am using it for something other than the dropdownlist, what do you mean by iterate over the result?

Comment: @Linger I thought that would maybe be more efficient because its less code, but maybe not. Also, I have about 10 dropdown lists so I thought it would be helpful.

Comment: I mean that if your query returns data that is used for something else but also has the result you need to populate the list, you can build your list by iterating over the result from you query using a loop.

Comment: If you really want the results as two columns in one query, you can do the queries as 2 separate subqueries, and join them on [row number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no logical reason to combine the two fields together in one query.  So you are better off just using two separate queries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColA FROM MyTable
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColB FROM MyTable
```

In going with ***mbeckish***'s suggestion (join them on row number) you could do the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5fb21/6/0)):

```
SELECT m.ColA, ms.ColB
FROM
(
  SELECT ColA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ColA) AS Row
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ColA
    FROM MyTable
  ) s 
) m
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT ColB, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ColB) AS Row 
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ColB
    FROM MyTable
  )  ss
) ms ON m.Row = ms.Row
```